# Fetch and display stream URL data

Tags: ios, xcode, url, stream

Following is stream url, not displaying any result in browser.

http://streamerapi.finance.yahoo.com/streamer/1.0?s=MSFT,GOOG&k=l10,c10,p20,g00,h00&callback=parent.yfs_u1f&mktmcb=parent.yfs_mktmcb&gencallback=parent.yfs_gencb

How to fetch data from above url and display on view in xcode ?

I have user following code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://streamerapi.finance.yahoo.com/streamer/1.0?s=MSFT,GOOG&k=l10,c10,p20,g00,h00&callback=parent.yfs_u1f&mktmcb=parent.yfs_mktmcb&gencallback=parent.yfs_gencb"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

NSString *loginString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD];

NSData *postData = [loginString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"Data : %@",data);
```

But it returns `NULL` result.
Please tell me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not answer your question but I recommend you using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) instead of NSURLRequest. Its really simple to use and has an amazing documentation.

Comment: Hi Corner and welcome to SO :) Tbh this is more suited to being posted as a comment than an answer, but nice one for getting involved!

Comment: Hi Corner,

Can you provide any sample code for it as i am new in iPhone development platform ???
It will help me a lot.